# Падежное окончание (буквенное наращение) в дате

Tags: орфография, числительные, даты, наращение

Как правильно: событие 2016-го года или событие 2016 года?
Нужно ли уточнять окончание в числительном?

Answer (score 1):

Обычно к цифрам года наращение не ставят, если за ним идет слово "год" (в любом падеже) или сокращение "г.". Но изредка можно встретить и такое написание, особенно если использованы только последние две цифры года. Поэтому большой ошибкой, думаю, не будет, просто излишне.

Answer (score 1):

Розенталь в своём [справочнике](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/31.htm) в примечании к §46 отмечает:

> Недопустимы [буквенные] наращения при количественных числительных, обозначениях дат, а также при римских цифрах: из 25 участников, 24 мая, VII съезд.

Поэтому правильным будет написание **24 мая 2016 года** и **в 2016–2018 гг.**.
С другой стороны, если нет месяца или слова **год** (сокращений **г.**, **гг.**), то эту запись нельзя трактовать как полноценную дату: **24-го у меня выходной, а 25-го — уже на работу**, **в 476-м Римская империя распалась**, потому как без контекста и непонятно, что речь о дате. Ещё одним исключением очевидно будет случай, когда речь идёт о десятке (десятках) лет: **в 1880-х годах** и **в 1920–1940-х годах** (сравните: **в 1920–1940 годах** — это уже другой временной интервал).

Answer (score 1):

**Наращением** называется падежное окончание имен числительных, выраженное в буквенной форме. Оно используется в записи только порядковых числительных:
**1-я** Тверская-Ямская улица; на **13-м** этаже; в **11-м** вагоне; **50-я** годовщина.

Случай с датой – именно тот, в котором **наращение не используется (при условии, что слово "год" или название месяца следуют за числом)**:
28 апреля 2018 года; 30 августа; **в 2016 году.**

В датах, в которых слово "год" или название месяца опущено или поставлено перед числом, **наращение используется**:
числа 10-го; **год 2016-й**; с 19 апреля по 28-е; в 20-х числах; грянул великий 1917-й; в 2061-м комета Галлея вновь приблизится к Земле.

***Событие 2016 года*** всколыхнуло весь мир.
Олимпийские игры – главное **событие 2016-го.**

[**Буквенные окончания (наращения) числительных**](http://www.primavista.ru/blog/2017/01/06/narashheniya-chislitelnyih/)